# Is the Finch audio library for iPhone capable of doing this?

Tags: iphone, audio, finch

I need to:

```
- start / stop sounds with lengths between 0.1 and 10 seconds
- change the playback volume
```

I want to / would like to / would be nice to have to:

```
- change the playback speed
- change the playback pitch / frequency
- pause an sound and resume playing it later
- play a sound backwards
```

Is Finch my best friend here?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749571/how-to-use-the-finch-audio-library-for-iphone

Comment: absolutely not a duplicate. The linked Q is about how to get started. This one is about what is possible and what not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version can do everything you want except changing the playback speed independently on the pitch (playing sound faster increases pitch) and playing sound backwards.